# how to get dynamic id of dynamically created textbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to perform keyup event via textbox id, and all textbox are dynamically created with onclick button event. for this i have to make 20 keyup function. if i use 20 keyup function then my code will become too lengthy and complex. instead of this i want to use a common function for all textbox. can anybody suggest me how to do it..thanks

here is what i am doing to solve it:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add Booking</button></div>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    </div>
    </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 2;
    $(".add_field_button").click(function() {
        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div id="target"><label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
            '" id="firsttextbox' + counter + '" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
            '" id="secondtextbox' + counter + '" value="" >  <a href="#" id="remove_field">Remove</a><input type="text" id="box' + counter + '" value="">sum</div>');
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

        counter++;

    });

    function check(a, b) {
        var first = a;
        var second = b;
        var temp = temp;
        var novalue = "";
        result = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return novalue;
        }
    }


    $(this).on("keyup", "#firsttextbox2", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = document.getElementById('firsttextbox2').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('secondtextbox2').value;
        var number = 2;
        result = check(a, b);
        document.getElementById('box2').value = result;

    });

    $(this).on("keyup", "#firsttextbox3", function(e) {
        var number = 3;
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = document.getElementById('firsttextbox3').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('secondtextbox3').value;
        result = check(a, b);
        document.getElementById('box3').value = result;
    });

    $(this).on("keyup", "#firsttextbox4", function(e) {
        var number = 4;
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = document.getElementById('firsttextbox4').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('secondtextbox4').value;
        result = check(a, b);
        final = document.getElementById('box4').value = result;
    });

    $(this).on("keyup", "#secondtextbox2", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = document.getElementById('firsttextbox2').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('secondtextbox2').value;

        result = check(a, b);
        document.getElementById('box2').value = result;

    });

    $(this).on("keyup", "#secondtextbox3", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = document.getElementById('firsttextbox3').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('secondtextbox3').value;
        result = check(a, b);

        document.getElementById('box3').value = result;
    });

    $(this).on("keyup", "#secondtextbox4", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = document.getElementById('firsttextbox4').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('secondtextbox4').value;
        result = check(a, b);

        document.getElementById('box4').value = result;
    });


    $(this).on("click", "#remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('#target').remove();
        counter--;

    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the snippet below to see how you can make this implementation more  modular and useable. The trick is to think: what do I want to do? I want to be able to add multiple inputs and add their value, printing the result in another input.

It comes down to using `classes` - since we are going to use the same kind of thing for every row. Then apply something that works for all classes. No IDs whatsoever! You can even use the `name` property of the input that contains the value you want to save. Using the `[]` in that property will even pass you back a nice array when POSTING!

I know this looks like a daunting lot, but remove my comments and the number of lines reduces dramatically and this kind of code is almost infinitely extendable and reusable.

But have a look, this works and its simple and - most of all - it's DRY (`don't repeat yourself` 0 once you do, re-evaluate as there should be a better way!)!

#### Update

You could also use a `<ol>`as a wrapper and then add an `<li>` to this every time, so you get automatic counting of boxes in the front end without any effort from your end! Actually, thats so nice for this that I have changed my implementation.

```js
var add = $('#add_boxes');
var all = $('#boxes');
var amountOfInputs = 2;
var maximumBoxes = 10;

add.click(function(event){
    
    // create a limit
    if($(".box").length >= maximumBoxes){
        alert("You cannot have more than 10 boxes!");
        return;
    }
        
    var listItem = $('<li class="box"></li>');
    // we will add 2 boxes here, but we can modify this in the amountOfBoxes value
    for(var i = 0; i < amountOfInputs; i++){
        listItem.append('<input type="text" class="input" />');
    }
    listItem.append('<input type="text" class="output" name="value" />');
    // Lets add a link to remove this group as well, with a removeGroup class
    listItem.append('<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeGroup" />')
    listItem.appendTo(all);
});

// This will tie in ANY input you add to the page. I have added them with the class `input`, but you can use any class you want, as long as you target it correctly.
$(document).on("keyup", "input.input", function(event){
    // Get the group
    var group = $(this).parent();
    // Get the children (all that arent the .output input)
    var children = group.children("input:not(.output)");
    // Get the input where you want to print the output
    var output = group.children(".output");
    // Set a value
    var value = 0;
    // Here we will run through every input and add its value
    children.each(function(){
        // Add the value of every box. If parseInt fails, add 0.
        value += parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    });
    // Print the output value
    output.val(value);
});

// Lets implement your remove field option by removing the groups parent div on click
$(document).on("click", ".removeGroup", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent(".box").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="boxes">
</ol>
<input type="button" value="Add a row" id="add_boxes" />
```

Comment: awesome code...simple ...clear...and best
am going to read your code from begining...helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can target all your textboxes, present or future, whatever their number, with a simple function like this :

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "input[type=text]", function(){
   var $textbox = $(this);
   console.log($textbox.val());
})

$("button").click(function(){
   $("#container").append('<input type="text" /><br>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" /><br>
  <input type="text" /><br>
  <input type="text" /><br>
</div>
<button>Create one more</button>
```

You don't need complicated generated IDs, not necessarily a class (except if you have other `input[type=text]` you don't want to conflict with). And you don't need to duplicate your code and write 20 times the same function. *Ever*. If you're duplicating code, you're doing wrong.

Comment: Nice, thats what I tried to get the other guy to answer :) Also love the mention of the `DRY` principle.

Comment: That may have been an opportunity to make a good answer yourself then :) Why didn't you?

Comment: If Maijray would have taken the suggestion his answer would have done just fine. All the answers have a piece of the puzzle and I think I would have nothing to add. Also, you beat me to it :) (I was typing it out but then two new posts appeared and you had the stuff I wanted to put in there, so yeah, theres that.)

Comment: So yeah, I ended up posting my answer after all. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Add classes "a" and "b" to the textboxes and "box" to the box. Then add data-idx attribute with the index (unused!?). Finally register the event handlers:

```
 $('.a').on('keyup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this)
    var $p = $this.parent()
    var a= this.value; 
    var b= $p.find('.b').val()
    var number =$this.data('idx') //unused!?
    var result = check(a,b)
    $p.find('.box').val(result)
 })
 $('.b').on('keyup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this)
    var $p = $this.parent()
    var a= $p.find('.a').val()  
    var b= this.value
    var result = check(a,b)
    $p.find('.box').val(result)
 })
```

Or a general one:

```
 $('.a,.b').on('keyup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $p = $(this).parent()
    var a= $p.find('.a').val()  
    var b= $p.find('.b').val()
    var result = check(a,b)
    $p.find('.box').val(result)
 })
```

Comment: This solution above is just another code duplication! 20 fields = 20 duplications! Nitish you really don't want to give up with that. @Somethingthere and myself have been giving you efficient solutions with event delegation, and you persist with repeating blocks of code. Well, so be it, if that's what you want.

Comment: @JeremyThille no, there are only these 2 event handlers, one for the firsttextbox* textboxes and onther one for the secondtextbox* texboxes. you can see the logic is not the same, but you can generalize the function when the `number`variable is not needed for 1 of the cases

Comment: General one helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a code-snippet which may give you some hint:

```
$(".add_field_button").click(function () 
{
    if (counter > 10) 
    {
        alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
        return false;
    }
    var txtBoxDiv = $("<div id='TextBoxDiv"+counter+"' style='float:left;width:10%; position:relative; margin-left:5px;' align='center'></div>");

     //creating the risk weight
     var txtBox1 = $('<input />', 
                           {
                            'id'     : 'fst_textbox_' + counter,
                            'name'   : 'textbox'+counter,
                            'type'   : 'text',
                            'class'  : 'input_field',
                            'onClick' : 'txtBoxFun(this,'+counter+')'
                          });
     var txtBox2 = $('<input />', 
                           {
                            'id'     : 'sec_textbox_' + counter,
                            'name'   : 'textbox'+counter,
                            'type'   : 'text',
                            'class'  : 'input_field',
                            'onClick' : 'txtBoxFun(this,'+counter+')'
                          });

    var txtBox3 = $('<input />', 
                           {
                            'id'     : 'sum_textbox_' + counter,
                            'name'   : 'textbox'+counter,
                            'type'   : 'text',
                            'class'  : 'input_field',
                          });

 $(txtBoxDiv).append(txtBox1).append(txtBox2);
 $(txtBoxDiv).append(txtBox3);
});

function txtBoxFun(obj, count)
{
   var idGet = $(obj).attr('id');
   var idArr = new Array();
   idArr = idGet.split("_");
   if(idArr[0] == "fst")
   {
      var sumTxt = parseInt(parseInt($(obj).val()) + parseInt($("#sec_textbox_"+count).val()));
   }
   else if(idArr[0] == "sec")
   {
      var sumTxt = parseInt(parseInt($(obj).val()) + parseInt($("#fst_textbox_"+count).val()));
   }
   $("#sum_textbox_"+count).val(sumTxt);

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass the 'counter' if you already have `this` element? You could easily use `prev()` or `next()`. I think better advice would have been to move away from using IDs.

Comment: var txtBox1 = $('<input />', 
                           {
                            'id'     : 'fst_textbox_' + counter,
                            'name'   : 'textbox'+counter,
                            'type'   : 'text',
                            'class'  : 'input_field',
                            'style'  : 'color:#777777; width: 90%; mergin-left: 30px;'
                            'onClick' : 'txtBoxFun(\'this\','+counter+')'
                          });


error in this line:   'onClick' : 'txtBoxFun(\'this\','+counter+')'

Comment: That's an awful lot of code if there are 20 text boxes. It's still duplicating a lot of code, using IDs, etc. and looks very clumsy to me.

Comment: @Nitish, my mistake, i edited my answer.. please look at the line.

Comment: still same error in  'onClick' : 'txtBoxFun(\'this\','+counter+')'

Comment: @Saswat even though your answer will do, I believe it not te be very versatile. It's very implementation specific and for this thing it should be easier than that. Again, classes would have helped more than trying to fix it with IDs.

Comment: how to pass id's with "this keyword" ??

Comment: Well, `this` is the element that has been acted upon, so you can get the id by doing `this.getAttribute("id")`

Comment: "this" keyword actualy sends the instance of the object. So using the $(obj).attr("id"), you can get the id of that particualr object

Comment: @somethinghere, i know its pretty lengthy and not the best approach, but based on the requirement,i though it may work. Besides he wanted to pass on the id..

Comment: @Nitish seriously, stop considering the IDs solution. You're on the wrong path. There are much more clever and simpler solutions around, using classes and not repeating code. And I'm not saying this for my own answer =)

Comment: @Saswat I know he wanted to do that, but only because his solution would only work if he knew the ID - but working with classes this can be enormously simplified and streamlined, and I think we should always try to explain what the best approach to a problem is, not just a way to simple make it work. But I understand where you're coming from as well.

Comment: @somethinghere, What do you mean by "I understand where you're coming from as well"?

Comment: @Nitish not taking advice from people who have given a clearly good answer will earn you a downvote. If you solution uses the IDs, it is not a better solution than the answers already provided. Saswat: I understand the 'let's solve the problem with as minimal changes as possible'. I just want to say that what I said was my opinion and we can differ :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `class` to all textboxes on which you want to perform `keyup` event and than using this `class` you can attach the event on elements which have that `class`. Here is an example

```
var html="";
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
   html += "<input type='text' id='txt" + i + "' class='someClass' />";
 }
 $("#testDiv").html(html);
```

Attach `keyup` event on elements which have class `someClass`.

```
 $(".someClass").keyup(function () {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
```

Comment: I like this ideas as IDs are not appropriate. Maybe, just to avoid any issues while adding, you could use `$(document).on("keyup", ".someClass", function(){});` so you only need to run this code once (since you are attaching an reattaching an event the 20th box inserted will trigger this twenty times since you are not unsetting the event using something like `off()`

Comment: No i have just attached it one time and it will attach one time. As this is not in loop and attached only once on `document.ready`.

Comment: It would still be better to attach it using `document.on(keyup, class, function)` since it would mean you can dynamically add as many as you want - which is what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

A little helper to combine with your favorite answer:

```
var uid = function () {
    var id = 0;
    return function () {
        return ++id;
    };
}();
```

Usage:

```
uid(); // 1
uid(); // 2
uid(); // 3
```

Comment: This is nice but it breaks down if you dont use it everywhere... I feel more comfortable with `while(documen.getElementById('prefix' + id) id++;` to be sure you get a fully unique id.