# How to get value from dynamic textbox with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a text box with id :

```
 <input type="text" name="jview_no[]" id="view'+$sr +'" value="1">
```

where :

```
$sr = ($(".my_tr_class").length + 1);
```

i wanted to put the value of that view+$sr to another textbox, so this is how i do it so far :

```
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="'+ $("#view"+$sr).val() + '" >
```

but the result is undefined.

the thing is, i don't really know how to do it the right way, would you guys please help me ?

thanks in advance

Comment: window.onload = function() { } u can check inside onload method.

Comment: Please double check your end output in browser. and then try to get value.

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706820/how-to-get-dynamic-id-of-dynamically-created-textbox-in-jquery/30707954      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232910/getting-the-value-of-dynamically-created-textbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you exactly want to achieve. If you have only two inputs you can use example below (this is only for your example), but if you have more inputs and you need to match these inputs together, you have read about `this` in javascript.

```js
$(document).on('keyup','input[name="jticket_no[]"]', function(){
  $(this).parent().next().children()[0].value = $(this).val()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%" class="table">
  <thead><tr><th>No.</th>
    <th>Views +5</th>
    <th>Payment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-details"><tr id="row1" class="jdr1">
    <td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-default">1</span><input type="hidden" value="6437" name="count[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Views" name="jticket_no[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required="" data-parsley-type="digits" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Payment" name="jamount[]"></td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1" class="jdr1">
    <td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-default">2</span><input type="hidden" value="6437" name="count[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Views" name="jticket_no[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required="" data-parsley-type="digits" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Payment" name="jamount[]"></td>
    
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hi there sorry for the long response, i'm still trying to implement the suggestions of mr kish and mr. suresh, but yes your code works, but only on row 0, i need it to works on all row that gonna be added by a button, would you help me please sir ?

Comment: look on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tyc2mar3/ If I am wrong change this fiddle and show me what excatly you want to achieve :)

Comment: thank you for your concern sir, i've editted my own fiddle. it's here : https://jsfiddle.net/9qtsefdk/6/ . as you can see, in this fiddle i able to add/remove row based on button click. the code you just gave works and able to copy from textbox 1 to textbox 2 on row 0 but unable to do it on row 1 or 2 or 3 etc... i need it to work on all row, and sorry my english is not too fluent.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4cwm7yvn/ I this this is good for you. Generelly you have a little mess in your code :) I edit my answer if it is good for please mark my answer